# Liberal coverage condition introduced in GHC 7.7 breaks code valid in GHC 7.6

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-inference, typeclass, typechecking

**The idea**

I'm writing a [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language), which compiles to Haskell.

Users of this language can define own immutable data structures and associated functions. By associated function I mean a function, which belongs to a data structure.
For example, user can write (in "pythonic" pseudocode):

```
data Vector a:
  x,y,z :: a
  def method1(self, x):
      return x
```

(which is equivalent to the following code, but shows also, that associated functions beheva like type classes with open world assumption):

```
data Vector a:
  x,y,z :: a
def Vector.method1(self, x):
  return x
```

In this example, `method1` is a function associated with `Vector` data type, and can be used like `v.testid(5)` (where `v` is instance of `Vector` data type).

I'm translating such code to Haskell code, but I'm facing a problem, which I'm trying to solve for a long time.

**The problem**

I'm trying to move the code from GHC 7.6 over [GHC 7.7 (which is pre-release of 7.8)](http://darcs.haskell.org/ghcBuilder/uploads/tn23/?C=M;O=D) (Newer versions can be compiled [from sources](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Building/GettingTheSources)). The code works perfectly under GHC 7.6, but does not under GHC 7.7.
I want to ask you how can I fix it to make it working in the new version of the compiler?

**Example code**

Lets see a simplified version of generated (by my compiler) Haskell code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}

import Data.Tuple.OneTuple

------------------------------
-- data types
------------------------------
data Vector a = Vector {x :: a, y :: a, z :: a} deriving (Show)
-- the Vector_testid is used as wrapper over a function "testid". 
newtype Vector_testid a = Vector_testid a

------------------------------
-- sample function, which is associated to data type Vector
------------------------------
testid (v :: Vector a) x = x

------------------------------
-- problematic function (described later)
------------------------------
testx x = call (method1 x) $ OneTuple "test"

------------------------------
-- type classes
------------------------------
-- type class used to access "method1" associated function
class Method1 cls m func | cls -> m, cls -> func where 
    method1 :: cls -> m func

-- simplified version of type class used to "evaluate" functions based on 
-- their input. For example: passing empty tuple as first argument of `call` 
-- indicates evaluating function with default arguments (in this example 
-- the mechanism of getting default arguments is not available)
class Call a b where
    call :: a -> b

------------------------------
-- type classes instances
------------------------------
instance (out ~ (t1->t1)) => Method1 (Vector a) Vector_testid out where
  method1 = (Vector_testid . testid)

instance (base ~ (OneTuple t1 -> t2)) => Call (Vector_testid base) (OneTuple t1 -> t2) where
    call (Vector_testid val) = val

------------------------------
-- example usage
------------------------------
main = do
    let v = Vector (1::Int) (2::Int) (3::Int)
    -- following lines equals to a pseudocode of ` v.method1 "test" `
    -- OneTuple is used to indicate, that we are passing single element.
    -- In case of more or less elements, ordinary tuples would be used.
    print $ call (method1 v) $ OneTuple "test"
    print $ testx v
```

The code compiles and works fine with GHC 7.6. When I'm trying to compile it with GHC 7.7, I'm getting following error:

```
debug.hs:61:10:
    Illegal instance declaration for
      ‛Method1 (Vector a) Vector_testid out’
      The liberal coverage condition fails in class ‛Method1’
        for functional dependency: ‛cls -> func’
      Reason: lhs type ‛Vector a’ does not determine rhs type ‛out’
    In the instance declaration for
      ‛Method1 (Vector a) Vector_testid out’
```

The error is caused by new rules of checking what functional dependencies can do, namely `liberal coverage condition` (as far as I know, this is `coverage condition` relaxed by using `-XUndecidableInstances`)

**Some attemps to fix the problem**

I was trying to overcome this problem by changing the definition of `Method1` to:

```
class Method1 cls m func | cls -> m where 
    method1 :: cls -> m func
```

Which resolves the problem with functional dependencies, but then the line:

```
testx x = call (method1 x) $ OneTuple "test"
```

is not allowed anymore, causing a compile error (in both 7.6 and 7.7 versions):

```
Could not deduce (Method1 cls m func0)
  arising from the ambiguity check for ‛testx’
from the context (Method1 cls m func,
                  Call (m func) (OneTuple [Char] -> s))
  bound by the inferred type for ‛testx’:
             (Method1 cls m func, Call (m func) (OneTuple [Char] -> s)) =>
             cls -> s
  at debug.hs:50:1-44
The type variable ‛func0’ is ambiguous
When checking that ‛testx’
  has the inferred type ‛forall cls (m :: * -> *) func s.
                         (Method1 cls m func, Call (m func) (OneTuple [Char] -> s)) =>
                         cls -> s’
Probable cause: the inferred type is ambiguous
```

**EDIT:**

It is also impossible to solve this issue using type families (as far as I know). If we replace `Method1` type class and instances with following code (or simmilar):

```
class Method1 cls m | cls -> m where 
    type Func cls
    method1 :: cls -> m (Func cls)

instance Method1 (Vector a) Vector_testid where
    type Func (Vector a) = (t1->t1)
    method1 = (Vector_testid . testid)
```

We would get obvious error `Not in scope: type variable ‛t1’`, because type families does not allow to use types, which does not appear on LHS of type expression.

**The final question**

How can I make this idea work under GHC 7.7? I know the new `liberal coverage condition` allows GHC devs make some progress with type checking, but it should somehow be doable to port idea working in GHC 7.6 over never compiler version.

(without forcing user of my DSL to introduce any further types - everything so far, like type class instances, I'm genarating using Template Haskell)

Comment: you could write a bug report, https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/query?status=new&status=assigned&status=reopened&group=priority&type=bug&order=id&desc=1

Comment: you could try to use Type Families instead of Functional Dependencies

Comment: I can't check at GHC 7.7, but ot looks like you could just get rid of `(out ~ (t1->t1))` part and rewrite a bit an instance to `instance Method1 (Vector a) Vector_testid (t -> t)`

Comment: @wit: of course I can, but it does not change anything :( the error is still the same and the `liberal coverage condition` is still not met.

Comment: @viorior: I've added "edit" section, please look at it. I see no way to use type families to solve thi problem. Did you have something else on mind? If I do not find any solution, I'll of course report this as bug.

Comment: @danilo2 May be it is possible to use Data Family instead of Type Family. Something like `instance ... where data Func cls = forall t. Func {unFunc :: t -> t }` But I'm really don't know how to unwrap data from the result

Comment: @viorior: I'll try it, but I'm sure it will not deliver such functionality as I want. I've updated slightly the first pseudocode, to show, that associated methods are like type classes (with open world assumption). Using Data Families I'll have to know all the associated methods when compiling the Data Family. 
Anyway I filled a GHC bug. If you are interested in it and are supporting it, feel free to leave there a comment :) https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8634#ticket

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a bug in GHC 7.7. It *was* a long-standing bug in GHC when it allowed instances
that violate functional dependencies. It seems, fortunately, that this problem is finally fixed. The error message emitted by GHC 7.7 is quite detailed, pointing out the problem with your instance `Method1 (Vector a) Vector_testid out`. Recall the meaning of functional
dependencies. Given

```
  class C a b | a -> b
```

it follows that if the types `a`, `b` and `b1` are such that `C a b` and `C a b1` 
both hold, it must be true that `b` and `b1` are the same. Let's look at your instance:

```
  Method1 (Vector a) Vector_testid (t1->t1)
```

If we have types `b` and `b1` that satisfy `Method1 (Vector Int) Vector_testid (b->b)`
and `Method1 (Vector a) Vector_testid (b1->b1)`, nothing at all implies that `b` and `b1` must be the same. Hence your instance is ill-formed. The fact that GHC 7.6 and before accepted the program was a well-known bug in GHC (discussed about every year).

What you seem to be trying is to define something like

```
 Method1 (Vector a) Vector_testid (forall t. t -> t)
```

Alas, this syntax is not allowed, although many worksrounds exist. One, for example, involves the Apply class (see the HList paper, for example). A simpler way is as follows

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}

-- import Data.Tuple.OneTuple
newtype OneTuple x = OneTuple x deriving Show

------------------------------
-- data types
------------------------------
data Vector a = Vector {x :: a, y :: a, z :: a} deriving (Show)

-- testx x = call (method1 x) $ OneTuple "test"
testx x = call x Method1 $ OneTuple "test"

-- associate methods to classes
class Methods cls m x y | cls m x -> y where
  call :: cls -> m -> x -> y

instance Methods (Vector a) Method1 x x where
  call self _ x = x

data Method1 = Method1 -- method label
```