# Building the haskell portion of geordi and ran into strange errors

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I am trying to build the haskell portion of the project [geordi](https://github.com/Eelis/geordi), and I have run into some strange errors

```
[dtscode@dtscode-manjaro geordi-master]$ cabal install
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring geordi-0...
Building geordi-0...
Failed to install geordi-0
Build log ( /home/dtscode/.cabal/logs/geordi-0.log ):
Configuring geordi-0...
Building geordi-0...
Preprocessing executable 'geordi-mkrt' for geordi-0...
Preprocessing executable 'geordi-local' for geordi-0...
[19 of 24] Compiling ErrorFilters     ( src/ErrorFilters.hs, dist/build/geordi-local/geordi-local-tmp/ErrorFilters.o )

src/ErrorFilters.hs:75:10:
    Illegal instance declaration for ‘Parser String st String’
      The liberal coverage condition fails in class ‘Parser’
        for functional dependency: ‘p -> st’
      Reason: lhs type ‘String’ does not determine rhs type ‘st’
    In the instance declaration for ‘Parser String st String’

src/ErrorFilters.hs:76:10:
    Illegal instance declaration for ‘Parser [String] st String’
      The liberal coverage condition fails in class ‘Parser’
        for functional dependency: ‘p -> st’
      Reason: lhs type ‘[String]’ does not determine rhs type ‘st’
    In the instance declaration for ‘Parser [String] st String’

src/ErrorFilters.hs:77:10:
    Illegal instance declaration for ‘Parser Char st Char’
      The liberal coverage condition fails in class ‘Parser’
        for functional dependency: ‘p -> st’
      Reason: lhs type ‘Char’ does not determine rhs type ‘st’
    In the instance declaration for ‘Parser Char st Char’
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
geordi-0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
[dtscode@dtscode-manjaro geordi-master]$
```

Unfortunately, I am not intimately familiar with haskell, and I can't make heads or tails of the errors other than that I need to install a library.

Comment: Newer versions of GHC are more strict about functional dependencies. You should try to build this code with GHC 7.6. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778588/liberal-coverage-condition-introduced-in-ghc-7-7-breaks-code-valid-in-ghc-7-6) is the explanation of why such code is no longer valid.

Comment: thank you! im using 7.8 so that makes sense

Comment: ... and [here](https://www.haskell.org/platform/) is the Haskell Platform, whose 2013.2.0.0 version ships with 7.6.2, on which the error does not trigger. Presumably the maintainer will update at some point.