# ambiguity check and liberal coverage condition failures for code working under GHC 7.6

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass, typechecking

I had a clever bit of type-level machinery that worked on GHC 7.6 but not later versions. Looking back I'm not totally sure why it ever worked, but regardless I would like to get back this functionality somehow:

```
{-# LANGUAGE 
    PolyKinds 
  , FunctionalDependencies , FlexibleInstances , FlexibleContexts
  , OverlappingInstances
  , ScopedTypeVariables
  , TypeFamilies
  , UndecidableInstances
 #-}
module M where

import Data.Proxy

-- | A relation between a (maybe-partially-applied) type and that type fully
-- applied.
class Applied t (tab :: *) | t -> tab where
    -- | Fully apply a type @t@ with polymorphic arguments, yielding @tab@.
    applied :: Proxy t -> Proxy tab

instance Applied (t a) tab=> Applied t tab where
    applied _ = applied (Proxy :: Proxy (t a))

instance t ~ tab=> Applied t tab where -- always matches when `t` is kind `*`
    applied _ = Proxy :: Proxy tab
```

This depends on the `tagged` library on GHC 7.6. We can use it like:

```
$ ghci-7.6.3
Prelude> :l M.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling M                ( M.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: M.
*M> 
*M> :t applied (Proxy :: Proxy Either)
applied (Proxy :: Proxy Either) :: Proxy (Either a a1)
*M> (return $ Right 'a') == applied (Proxy :: Proxy Either)
True
```

However this doesn't compile on at least GHC 7.8.3 or later:

```
$ ghci-7.8.3
GHCi, version 7.8.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> :l M.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling M                ( M.hs, interpreted )

M.hs:19:10:
    Could not deduce (Applied (t a0) tab)
      arising from the ambiguity check for an instance declaration
    from the context (Applied (t a) tab)
      bound by an instance declaration:
                 Applied (t a) tab => Applied t tab
      at M.hs:19:10-42
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    In the ambiguity check for:
      forall (k :: BOX) (k1 :: BOX) (t :: k1 -> k) tab (a :: k1).
      Applied (t a) tab =>
      Applied t tab
    To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
    In the instance declaration for ‘Applied t tab’

M.hs:19:10:
    Illegal instance declaration for ‘Applied t tab’
      The liberal coverage condition fails in class ‘Applied’
        for functional dependency: ‘t -> tab’
      Reason: lhs type ‘t’ does not determine rhs type ‘tab’
    In the instance declaration for ‘Applied t tab’
Failed, modules load
```

I think the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20813151/176841) is related, but I don't yet understand the suggestion.

It's possible I might be able to work around this. The only place I use this class is in a signature of the form:

```
instance (Foo tab, Applied t tab)=> Bar (Proxy t) where
```

Which might indicate I want to make `Foo` kind-polymorphic, but this is in a big complicated library and I don't know if that change would be possible.

Comment: It was simply a bug that 7.6 ever accepted this. See the discussion on [8634](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8634), which points at [1241](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/1241), [2247](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/2247), and [8356](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8356) for further clarification. To say what you can do instead, we will probably have to have a bit more context about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to assert for some `t :: * ^ n -> *` that there is an instance `Foo (t a_1 a_2 .. a_n)`, where `a_i` are distinct type variables. If this is the case, you can replace `Applied (t a) tab` with `Applied (t X) tab` where X is any type. So long as X is defined in your module and not exported, nobody can actually make an instance with that type, so any instance that unifies with `X` must have been given with a type variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your ghci example works for me in ghc-7.8.3 if I get rid of the FD, and enable `-XAllowAmbiguousTypes`. That extension will require you to annotate (using `ScopedTypeVariables`) the type of that `applied` function when it is used in `instance (Foo tab, Applied t tab)=> Bar (Proxy t)`.